# Android Foreground Service that works while app is closed

Tags: android, file-upload, foreground-service

How to make an unstoppable service. That'll be working in background. (this service will be used to upload large file to server) With these case.

## If user closes app while service is running, it should continue working

I don't know what should be used in this case. All I need is to make service work in background... Can anyone help me with that?
Note that minimum sdk is 17

Comment: please use the following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4360074/creating-a-service-in-android

Comment: I have tried service and intent service but when i closed app, i can't understand what's happened, all i get is retrofit stop it's task.. Don't knoe why

Answer (score 0):

You can use `WorkManager's` `OneTimeWorkRequest` for uploading large files to the server.

But still, if your system doesn't have enough resources this `work` will be canceled by the system. So if you detect the `work` has failed then you can schedule a `periodic work request` to upload the file later when system's resources are free.

[WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager)

[OneTimeWork Request](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/OneTimeWorkRequest)

[PeriodicWork Request](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/PeriodicWorkRequest)